# NSDate and the next day

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsdate

What I used to do was using the timestamp and then adding 86400 seconds ( 24 * 60 * 60 ). As I read a recent question on stackoverflow noting that that is not correct for every day, I want to change this.

So the next thing I came up with was by using NSDateComponents. I simply get the current day and add 1. Now I was wondering how "smart" that is. Like if the day is equal to 31, does it set the day to 1 and the month to whatever it is +1 ( or when it is 12 to 1 again ) ? I can do this manually but that would only work properly for the gregorian calendar so I don't really know whether that would be a good solution either..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is smart, unless you want it to be dumb.

From [the documentation for `-[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCEBJHG):

> If you specify no options (you pass 0), overflow in a unit carries into the higher units (as in typical addition).

If you did *not* want units overflowing into higher units, then you would pass "`NSWrapCalendarComponents`" as the value of the `options:` parameter.

Comment: Cool, thanks -- it was your tweet that notified me of this bug in my code btw :P

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful of DST. It is different for various time zones. **AND It happens at Midnight**
I believe that if you call [NSCalendar date by addingComponents:toDate:options] and your date is between 11-12 pm, you risk missing or re-running a day because of DST. 
To get around this, is suggest changing your date to noon on the day and then adding the day.

```
// increment by 1 calendar day
// and convert back to NSDate objects
NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comps setDay:1];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
[gregorian setTimeZone:self.myTimeZone]; // time zone of location;  

// Use local noontime for the date to avoid problems around
// midnight, particularly near daylightsavings time discontinuities. 
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

dateComponents.hour = 12;
NSDate* noonDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:noonDate options:0];
```

I'm not sure about the options:0 setting, but I did test this pretty thoroughly. I use it to get an array of with 10 days of dates. It gives correct wrapping around the various day/month/year discontinuities. Check out SunPose Rise Set on the app store if you want to test it. (yes, it's free)